# php & mysql db insert from Json file

Tags: php, mysql, json, insert

as some of you suggested me, I'm trying to automate mysql link to json source and update database.

So I'm creating my php file to insert data.
I dunno why it's not working the code down here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="table-db.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Monetary Marker 12h update</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//connect to mysql db
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully <br />";


// NAME funzione
insertData:
//VALUES from JSON
$jsondata = file_get_contents('exchanges.json');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//convert json object to php associative array
$countryID = $data['country']['id'];
$countryName = $data['country']['name'];
$countryCurrency = $data['country']['currency'];
$buyRate = $data['country']['buy_rate'];
$sellRate = $data['country']['sell_rate'];

//VALUES DATE&HOUR
date_default_timezone_set('UTC+1');
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$spreadBuySell = (1/$buyRate)-$sellRate;

foreach($data as $item) {   
$sqlinsert = ("INSERT INTO MonetaryExchange12h   (countryID,countryName,countryCurrency,buyRate,sellRate,BuySellSpread,saveDateTime) 
VALUES    ('".$item['$countryID']."','".$item['$countryName']."','".$item['$countryCurrency']."','".$item['$buyRate']."','".$item['$sellRate']."','".$item['$spreadBuySell']."','".$item['$timestamp']."')");
    }

if ($conn->query($sqlinsert) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully <br />";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sqlinsert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
};
$conn->close();
?> 

<?php
// TABLE SHOW TEST
//connect to mysql db
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully <br />";

$sql = "SELECT   countryID,countryName,countryCurrency,buyRate,sellRate,BuySellSpread,saveDa teTime FROM MonetaryExchange12h ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
echo '<tr><th>Country ID</th><th>Country</th><th>Currency</th><th>buy  Rate</th><th>sell Rate</th><th>Spread</th><th>Time Record</th></tr>';
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["countryID"]."</td><td>".$row["countryName"]."</td><td>".$row["countryCurrency"]."</td><td>".$row["buyRate"]."</td><td>".$row["sellRate"]."</td><td>".$row["BuySellSpread"]."</td><td>".$row["saveDateTime"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
};
$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is a part of my json file:

```
{"country": [{"id":24,"name":"Argentina","currency":"ARS","buy_rate":0.046,"sell_rate": 30.8747}, {"id":35,"name":"Australia","currency":"AUD","buy_rate":0.0799,"sell_rate": 99.5156},{"id":13,"name":"Bosnia and  Herzegovina","currency":"BAM","buy_rate":0.0788,"sell_rate":20.4999}],"load":0.59583497047424}
```

Can you tell me where's my wrong?

**1st UPDATE**

well first of all thx for answer. i've tested code, but it return me only 1 entry, more precisely the last one. what am I missing?

```
 $jsondata = file_get_contents('exchanges.json');
 $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
 foreach($data['country'] as $item) {
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO MonetaryExchange12h   (countryID,countryName,countryCurrency,buyRate,sellRate) VALUES ('{$item['id']}','{$item['name']}','{$item['currency']}','{$item['buy_rate']}','{$item['sell_rate']}')";
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain exactly what is not working.  Also, while SO is a pretty tight knit community, we need a bit more context than "as some of you suggested...".

Comment: The associative array part is wrong, not DB part. you need to iterate $data["country"] not $data itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you had error reporting on, you'd see that your decoded json array is an associative array. So your code won't work.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

[image: json object]

Meaning: You'd have to loop through the countries or fetch the first one..

```
foreach($data['country'] as $country) {
    $countryID = $country['id'];
    //...add the rest
}
```

Or simply do only the first element:

```
$countryID = $data['country'][0]['id'];
//...add the rest.
```

---

**Notes**

- You're also overwriting your `$sqlinsert` variable as you close that `foreach` off prematurely.. So it'll only ever enter the last values.
- You're redundantly setting the variables `$countryID`/`$countryName`/..etc, you should change your foreach loop to something like this:

---

```
foreach($data['country'] as $item) {
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO table (column,.....) VALUES ('{$item['id']}',...)";
    if ($conn->query($sqlinsert) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully <br />";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sqlinsert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've update my post with the code error it return me.
thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally did it.
Thx for your help.

The final code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="table-db.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Monetary Marker 12h update</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

//check errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

//connect to mysql db
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully <br />";


// NOME funzione
insertData:

$url = "http://esimeconomytools.altervista.org/monetarymarket/exchanges.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$out = json_decode($json, true);
$dataCountry = $out['country'];
//$idCountry = $out['country']['id'];

foreach($dataCountry as $country) { 
$idCountry = addslashes($country['id']); 
$nameCountry = addslashes($country['name']); 
$Currency = addslashes($country['currency']);
$buyRate = addslashes($country['buy_rate']);
$sellRate = addslashes($country['sell_rate']);


$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO MonetaryExchange12h    (countryID,countryName,countryCurrency,buyRate,sellRate) VALUES  ('$idCountry','$nameCountry','$Currency','$buyRate','$sellRate')";

if ($conn->query($sqlinsert) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully <br />";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sqlinsert . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}};
$conn->close();
?>
```

Pay particular attention on where do you put ";" at the end of INSERT INTO command.
There, it will end the activity of the script.

So if you are using "foreach", you will have to put ";" at the very end of the function or you'll interrupt the loop after 1st (or last) insertion.

Thx everybody.
If anyone of you have a link to a good tutorial for cross-domain JSON data retrieve in php, is welcome.

Alberto